# Is it bad practice to allow a UINavigationController to push view controllers that could lead to a repeating stack?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm building an app with a UINavigationController where I push a UIViewControllers, and IBActions on one of the classes can cause another instance of the first type to be pushed:

ViewControllerType1 --> ViewControllerType2 --> ViewControllerType3 --> ViewControllerType1

As you can see, its possible to have no 'end' to the stack.

Is this bad practice to have a never ending cycle like this?
Should a UINavigationController stack be used with an 'end' in mind?

Comment: A good counter-example would be the YouTube app - you can move to endless related videos. I tried then and it's at least twenty, but I'm pretty sure there's no softcoded limit.

Comment: I just looked and Twitter does it too. Tweet --> Author Profile --> Author Tweets --> Original Tweet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to allow a "cycle" if that's what the user expects.

If you expect (and want to allow) the user to create deep stacks, you should try to minimize the amount of private state in each view controller.  For example, if two view controllers on the stack both show the same information to the user, you should make both view controllers share the same underlying object holding that information.

You should also make sure each view controller releases as much as it can if it receives the [`didReceiveMemoryWarning` message](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didReceiveMemoryWarning) (if that view controller is not on top of the stack).

Comment: One tricksy advanced method (which may not be totally desirable) would be to check when displaying a list of items of `ViewControllerType1` that you don't show any of the ones in the current nav controller stack. That way the user (who is assumedly aware of which items he/she has looked at) can keep going but you also guarantee the stack is unique, and so it's less likely to be space-redundant or undesired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that this is not the best practice - it makes navigation back rather cumbersome unless you implement functions that pop to root or at least low into the hierarchy.

Also, from my experience you should not be absolutely trusting that the retain counts of such arranged controllers are calculated correctly - I've tried a similar approach once and popping a view controller resulted in it in being released while still technically on the stack.

Also - resource-wise it is horrible - you have no idea how many viewcontrollers you might end up having.